# Ruby - Reading a file, replacing contents, then closing

Tags: ruby

How do you open a file, read it, then write to it replacing the entire contents, and close it?

I could do this:

```
File.open('foo.bin', 'r') do |f|
  contents = f.read
end
# do something with the contents
File.open('foo.bin', 'w') do |f|
  f.print contents
end
```

But there are 2 IO open steps and 2 IO close steps in that and doubling the IO steps seems like a total waste, not to mention much harder on the disk with as many times as it is likely to happen in my script.

Is there a way to open, read, overwrite, then close?

Comment: Consider using a better data format that doesn't require you to read in every single piece of data just to process it. SQLite is always a good start. Also, did you profile the code before deciding this is what is making it slow?

Comment: Due to business decisions way above my head, I have to keep it entirely local and portable to any machine without external dependancies. Which pretty much removes any DB possibility. And the size is far too big to store it all in memory. It leaves IO as my only option, and my question remains.

Comment: And yes, this is one of several slowdowns. I am tackling each, including this one.

Comment: SQLite does not need a database server, just a Ruby gem. The database is just a .sqlite file, plus an index file. You access it via a client library, not a database server. https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby Maybe you should ask a question about your data design?

Comment: I've spent the last 2 hours taking your advice about sqlite3, and using different implementations, single db file, breaking the db files up to various degrees, and the best i can get it benchmarking 6 times slower than just marshaling the objects to file, far too slow to be acceptable. A MySQL db on an external machine previously proved faster by about 30%, but is no longer possible under the requirements imposed.

Comment: Sorry it didn't work out. SQLite was just a stab in the dark, there's not enough information to offer better suggestions, and I without seeing your SQLite implementation I can't say how to improve it. Again, you should ask a question about how to improve your data model and process; reading and writing millions of individual files is never going to be efficient. You have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if you didn't profile your code, do it now. An extra file open/close is unlikely to be the cause of your slow down. Profiling will show where the real issue is.

I'm not convinced this will be any faster, but here are the general steps to do this with a single open and close.

1. Open for read & write.
2. Read the whole file (not line by line).
3. Truncate the file.
4. Go back to the beginning.
5. Write.
6. Close.

In Ruby, you do that like so:

```
# Open the file for read/write.
File.open("test.data", "r+") { |f|
    # Read the whole file
    contents = f.read

    # Truncate the file
    f.truncate(0)

    # Jump back to the beginning
    f.rewind

    # Write the new content
    f.write("new stuff\n")
}
```

Comment: At least on my system (Ruby 2.4, OS X), `truncate` doesn't seem to adjust the position, so you might have to `rewind` it, too.

Comment: @Stefan Yeah, I figured it was a bit fishy. I'll add a rewind, thanks. What happens without the rewind?

Comment: Without `rewind` everything up to the current position is filled with null characters, although this might be implementation specific.

Comment: You could also rewind, overwrite the old content and truncate the file to the new content's length.